# pgfplots line from top to bottom (0% to 100%) but at given x value

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw a straight line from the top of a graph to its bottom without defining specific y-values but only saying from 0% to 100% of the y-axis. The x-value, however, should be set in the coordinate system of the graph.

I'm running `compat=1.15`, so I don't need to add `axis cs:` before the coordinates to let them match the real graph.

I think, that I'd need to use two different coordinate systems. For the x-value the default `axis cs` comes in handy but for the y-value I'd rather need the `axis description cs`. Please note that the default graphs in pgfplots do have a little margin on each side, so even if I would enter the y-values manually the line wouldn't be from the very top to the very bottom, which it should be.

As can be seen in the MWE, setting a value that is smaller than the smallest plotting value gives the correct result, so a possible hack could be to just use extreme numbers, but I don't like that idea.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {x},
        ylabel = {y},
    ]
        \addplot+[mark=none, smooth] plot coordinates {
            (200, 20)
            (210, 22)
            (220, 23)
            (230, 25)
            (240, 35)
            (250, 40)
            (260, 36)
            (270, 27)
            (280, 20)
            (290, 19)
            (300, 15)
        };

        \draw (250, 0) -- (250, 40);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\draw (current axis.south-|<x>, 0) -- (current axis.north-|<x>,0);` where `<x>` is your desired x value.

Comment: Could you please explain (in short terms) what this does?

Comment: Or `\draw (250,0 |- {axis description cs:0,0}) -- (250,0 |- {axis description cs:0,1});`

Comment: @Sam Sure, the `-|` means that I want to use the intersection of a _horizontal_ (`-`) line coming from the first coordinate, and a _vertical_ (`|`) line coming from the second coordinate. Similarly, the `|-` means the same, but the other way around. In principle this means that for `-|` I am using the `y` coordinate of the first point, and the `x` coordinate of the second point, discarding the `x` of the first point and the `y` of the second point.

Comment: @Sam With first and second coordinate I mean the coordinates _within_ the parentheses. So `(current axis.south-|250,0)` uses the `y` value of `current axis.south`, which is the bottom of the axis, and the `x` value of the point `(250,0)`, expressed in the `axis cs` due to `compat=1.15`.

Comment: That's neat. Wow! Thank you very much for that simple solution and the great explanation!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.

Comment: @Max Can you turn your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with

```
\draw (current axis.south-|<x>, 0) -- (current axis.north-|<x>,0);
```

Or as Stefan Pinnow [commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447284/pgfplots-line-from-top-to-bottom-0-to-100-but-at-given-x-value?noredirect=1#comment1123595_447284) with

```
\draw (<x>,0 |- {axis description cs:0,0}) -- (<x>,0 |- {axis description cs:0,1});
```

Which both use the `perpendicular` coordinate system, which takes two points (let's call them `p` and `q`), draws a vertical line from one and a horizontal line from the other, and returns the intersection point of these lines. The implicit syntax can be used as: `(p-|q)` or `(p|-q)`.

The `-|` means that I want to use the intersection of a horizontal (`-`) line coming from `p`, and a vertical (`|`) line coming from `q`. Similarly, the `|-` means the same, but the other way around. In principle this means that for `-|` I am using the `y` coordinate of `p`, and the `x` coordinate of `q`, discarding the `x` of `p` and the `y` of `q`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {x},
        ylabel = {y},
    ]
        \addplot+[mark=none, smooth] plot coordinates {
            (200, 20)
            (210, 22)
            (220, 23)
            (230, 25)
            (240, 35)
            (250, 40)
            (260, 36)
            (270, 27)
            (280, 20)
            (290, 19)
            (300, 15)
        };

        \draw (current axis.south-|240, 0) -- (current axis.north-|240,0);

        \draw (260,0 |- {axis description cs:0,0}) -- (260,0 |- {axis description cs:0,1});

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]