# draw parallel line abscissa

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to be able to draw a line parallel to the y axis but I can't manage to do it.

I try this code :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.35,1)},anchor=south},
    xlabel = {Intensité I ($\unit{\mA}$)} ,
    ylabel = {Tension U ($\unit{\V}$)},
    xmin = -100, xmax = 200,
    ymin = -0.5, ymax = 13,
    xtick=\empty,]
\addplot[mark=none, red, very thick] expression[domain=-80:180]{y=100};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to *plot* a line

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={->},
x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=north},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.35,1)},anchor=south},
xlabel={Intensité I ($\unit{\mA}$)} ,
ylabel={Tension U ($\unit{\V}$)},
xmin=-100, xmax=200,
ymin=-0.5, ymax=13,
xtick=\empty,
]
\addplot[mark=none, red, very thick] coordinates {(100,-0.5) (100,13)};
\addplot[mark=none, red, very thick, domain=-0.5:13, samples=2] (100,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with vertical line]

To `\draw` a line see e.g. [pgfplots line from top to bottom (0% to 100%) but at given x value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447284/pgfplots-line-from-top-to-bottom-0-to-100-but-at-given-x-value)

Comment: @JohnKormylo: `(100,x)` *is* the parametric plot - maybe just a bit confusing that the parameter(variable) is not renamed. You could do `variable=t` and then `(100,t)`.